# $p$(ain)-adic number sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to figure out how $p$-adic numbers work and currently am having trouble wrapping my head around how they work, so I made a pun! HAH!

Jokes aside, I am working on this question

> Show that the sequence $(3,34,334,3334,.....)$ is equal to $2/3$ in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_5$

I assume they mean it converges to $2/3$ in the $5$-adic integers by the question. My big issue is that I am struggling to properly attack it. One question immediately comes to mind is: does $334$ mean

> $334=3\cdot 5^0+3\cdot 5^1+4\cdot 5^2$

as all $p$-adic numbers can be written as such, or what does it exactly mean? If so, how would I go on exactly demonstrating this? Their initial peculiarity, especially with increased number decreases distance is throwing me off quite a bit.

Comment: The first $3$ ought to be a $4$ when you spell out $334$.

Comment: It says 3 in my exercise here, I would imagen it being 4 too by pattern but that's all I could go on.

Comment: I assume you only saw the initial version of my comment.

Comment: Ah yes my bad I see

Comment: Well. The first entry of a sequence never affects its limit, so why would we waste breath pondering whether it begins with a $3$ or a $4$ ;-)

Comment: It is still not correct. It is really like if it would be an integer. The $4$ is withe the $5^0$ not the $5^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence $(a_n)=(4,34,334,3334,\ldots)$ satisfies $3a_n-2\to 0$ for $n\to \infty$ in the $5$-adic topology. You can "see" this by considering
\begin{align*}
3\cdot 4 & = 12 \\
3\cdot 34 & = 102 \\
3\cdot 334 & = 1002 \\
3\cdot 3334 & = 10002
\end{align*}
etc. Hence for the metric $d$ we have $d(a_m,a_n)=\frac{1}{5^n}$ for all $m>n$, so that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, which converges to $2/3$.

Comment: I have noticed that pattern when multiply by 3 but not gone much further, how does this help?

Comment: I see, hmmm thank you that does help for now

Answer (score 3):

Here, the notation is in the usual base $10$, so the number $a_n = 33\ldots34$ simply denotes

$$a_n = 3 \times 10^n + 3 \times 10^{n-1} + \ldots + 3 \times 10 + 4 = 1 + 3\sum_{k = 0}^n 10^k = 1 + \frac{10^{n+1}-1}{3}$$

Now, in the $5$-adic topology, the sequence $(10^n)_{n \ge 0}$ goes to $0$ at infinity because $\left|10^n\right|_5 = \frac{1}{5^n} \longrightarrow 0$, so you get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1 + \frac{0-1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$